# All headers pass, hotmail still marks as spam

Tags: email, spam, spf, smtp-headers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Does hotmail still reject my emails?](https://serverfault.com/questions/434703/why-does-hotmail-still-reject-my-emails)

So I've been working a long time on fixing the Hotmail issue, but nothing seems to work:

- Created my SPF records with the [microsoft tool](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/)
- Enabled reverse DNS (and checked)
- Checked MX records
- Checked for blacklists
- Added DKIM
- Did every test on [MxToolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/)

I have a VPS set up with my main domain as nameserver. All my clients domains have my NS-records and they can edit the DNS in DirectAdmin.

This is my last test:

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR3P+ctWZsO+J
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=pass (sender IP is xx.xx.xx.74) header.from=test@domain.nl; dkim=none header.d=domain.nl; x-hmca=pass
X-SID-PRA: test@domain.nl
X-DKIM-Result: None
X-Message-Status: n:0:n
X-SID-Result: Pass
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD0z
X-Message-Info: 2etWe3f/w1fPzVW+BbVPM9PFXf465RcPLor8OGrY1xCKjcZ3x50V531sP8e5m4GsNpw5CK5W6cKUlwY8DHbBWB+Lj7NXmhBNTxxMZ1FagXmP51VCk2ej+MGHbXDDN2lXWLgrobPK8+Ohie8Rd2eMTA==
Received: from server.domain.nl ([xx.xx.xx.74]) by COL0-MC1-F46.Col0.hotmail.com with     Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
 Wed, 1 Aug 2012 05:19:48 -0700

Received: from axx-xx-xx-230.adsl.xs4all.nl ([xx.xx.xx.230] helo=MyPcName)
by server.domain.nl with smtp (Exim 4.80)
(envelope-from <test@domain.nl>)
id 1SwXty-0002Sa-W0; Wed, 01 Aug 2012 06:19:47 -0600

Message-ID: <C2520F61140C46728CDC139B11814FAB@GijsPaulidesPC>
From: "Tester" <test@domain.nl>
To: "My Hotmail Name" <my@hotmail.com>,
"Spam checker" <check@isnotspam.com>,
"Spam checker 2" <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>
Subject: 
Date: Wed, 1 Aug 2012 14:19:39 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="----=_NextPart_000_02E9_01CD6FF0.AFA988D0"
X-Priority: 3
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
Importance: Normal
X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 15.4.3555.308
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V15.4.3555.308
Return-Path: test@domain.nl
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 01 Aug 2012 12:19:48.0704 (UTC) FILETIME=[F1B2F600:01CD6FDF]
Dit is een meerdelig bericht in de MIME-indeling.
------=_NextPart_000_02E9_01CD6FF0.AFA988D0
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
SOME CONTENT
------=_NextPart_000_02E9_01CD6FF0.AFA988D0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY dir=3Dltr>
<DIV dir=3Dltr>
<DIV style=3D"FONT-FAMILY: 'Calibri'; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 12pt">
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
SOME TEXT</DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>

------=_NextPart_000_02E9_01CD6FF0.AFA988D0--
```

Comment: It's Hotmail. There's nothing you can do about them except to ask recipients to add you to their safe list.

Comment: Are you sure? Because there are so many `how-to`'s on fixing the spam mark.

Comment: Same issue here.. all PASS and my mails goes to spam!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matters or not but your test message doesn't actually contain any text.  It's possible its marking it as SPAM because it does not appear to be a valid e-mail message.  Try actually adding a body to the message and see if that works.

Comment: I removed the text and I checked with multiple contents.

Comment: Removed what text? I meant you should add a message to the body of the email.  Make sure you have a subject and a body.

Comment: Ugh, I don't know what I just wrote... I tried out multiple kinds of contents. Normal text like: "About out meeting", "Hello, it was blabla..".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not on any DNSBL? It could be the ISP / provider has others already on the list and you're guilty by association.

Comment: I check the IP of my server on multiple lists. Getting a green light from about 150 Blacklist servers. Maybe you have a list I didn't check with?

Comment: dnsbl.info was all I had, sounds like you've used it. Check for other IPs on that range... might return some bad results :(