# Why Outlook, Hotmail and Live return 250 Mail queued for delivery, but they never deliver it?

Tags: email, smtp

Ok, i've been seeing this the last week, tought it could be gone in a few days by itself, since i wasn't blacklisted and my DNS entries are all ok, but when i try to send e-mails to some user at Outlook, Live or Hotmail, i get this:

```
2015-02-11 14:54:58 1YLaYz-0000IT-I1 H=localhost.localdomain (higipel.com.br) [127.0.0.1]:41242 Warning: "SpamAssassin as cpaneleximscanner detected OUTGOING smtp message as NOT spam (-1.0)"
2015-02-11 14:54:59 1YLaYz-0000IT-I1 <= teste@higipel.com.br H=localhost.localdomain (higipel.com.br) [127.0.0.1]:41242 P=esmtpa A=dovecot_login:teste@higipel.com.br S=3532 id=5f640648ff1df4f59148f5c9cbbbd67b@higipel.com.br T="Lorem Ipsum" for [privarypreserved]@outlook.com
2015-02-11 14:54:59 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1YLaYz-0000IT-I1
2015-02-11 14:54:59 1YLaYz-0000IT-I1 SMTP connection outbound 1423673699 1YLaYz-0000IT-I1 higipel.com.br [privarypreserved]@outlook.com
2015-02-11 14:54:59 SMTP connection from localhost.localdomain (higipel.com.br) [127.0.0.1]:41242 closed by QUIT
2015-02-11 14:55:01 1YLaYz-0000IT-I1 => [privarypreserved]@outlook.com R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=mx1.hotmail.com [65.55.37.72] X=TLSv1:AES256-SHA:256 C="250  <5f640648ff1df4f59148f5c9cbbbd67b@higipel.com.br> Queued mail for delivery"
2015-02-11 14:55:01 1YLaYz-0000IT-I1 Completed
```

And the weird thing is, i have a few hundred domains under 3-4 IP's at most, but just 4-5 domains are presenting this 'problem'

Anyone found a solution for this yet?

Comment: Did you look in "Junk"?

Comment: Yes, several times, even a day after i sent the test e-mail, not even a clue of the e-mail in there. :/

Comment: The email was accepted by the recipient server but it didn't make it to the mailbox. It's got to be caught in a spam filter somewhere on the recipient end.

Comment: There're no filters on account level os the recipient. @sebix, really? :/ No solution until now?

Comment: The solution is to boycott these providers. They talk about free market, let's do it. (When I know of a solution, I'm sure I'll post it here)

Comment: @JorgeFerrari Do you have SPF and DKIM in place?

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A: http://serverfault.com/questions/536079/cant-send-email-from-postfix-to-hotmail

Comment: SPF and DKIM are important. I haven't tried Live, but GMail junked my emails even after SPF and DKIM. In addition I had to set a DMARC policy, after that my mails started to flow normally. Give DMARC a try.

Comment: Have you reviewed their faq here: https://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's because of Microsoft's SmartScreen.

You gotta be in concordance with these topics:

- Setup a SPF record
- Setup DKIM
- Setup a DMARC record
- Setup a reverse DNS record
- HELO must be a host name not an IP
- Make sure that your IP is not on a blacklist
- Use a static IP address for your server
- Sign up for JMRP and SNDS

I've followed [this article](https://skrilnetz.net/mail-server-how-to-convince-hotmail-to-deliver-your-messages-to-the-receipts-mailbox/), which solved the same problem you're having.